# VBA outlook exception object, array index out of bound

Tags: arrays, vba, exception, outlook

The below codes are from Outlook 2010 developer reference, explaining the use of " Exception.AppointmentItem Property"

However while pasting and runing it, it pops up "array index out of bounds (run time error -2147352567(80020009) , and debug points to 
Set myException = myRecurrPatt.Exceptions.item(1)

```
'Get the recurrence pattern for the master
'AppointmentItem. Access the collection of
'exceptions to the regular appointments.
Set myRecurrPatt = myApptItem.GetRecurrencePattern
Set myException = myRecurrPatt.Exceptions.item(1)

'Display the original date, time, and subject
'for this exception.
MsgBox myException.OriginalDate & ": " & saveSubject
```

The problem persists after I changed the index to 0. Please help, thank you!

Below is the full oringinal code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub cmdExample()

    Dim myApptItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim myRecurrPatt As Outlook.RecurrencePattern
    Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder
    Dim myItems As Outlook.Items
    Dim myDate As Date
    Dim myOddApptItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim saveSubject As String
    Dim newDate As Date
    Dim myException As Outlook.Exception

    Set myApptItem = Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)
    myApptItem.Start = #2/2/2003 3:00:00 PM#
    myApptItem.End = #2/2/2003 4:00:00 PM#
    myApptItem.Subject = "Meet with Boss"

    'Get the recurrence pattern for this appointment
    'and set it so that this is a daily appointment
    'that begins on 2/2/03 and ends on 2/2/04
    'and save it.
    Set myRecurrPatt = myApptItem.GetRecurrencePattern
    myRecurrPatt.RecurrenceType = olRecursDaily
    myRecurrPatt.PatternStartDate = #2/2/2003#
    myRecurrPatt.PatternEndDate = #2/2/2004#
    myApptItem.Save

    'Access the items in the Calendar folder to locate
    'the master AppointmentItem for the new series.
    Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    Set myItems = myFolder.Items
    Set myApptItem = myItems("Meet with Boss")

    'Get the recurrence pattern for this appointment
    'and obtain the occurrence for 3/12/03.
    myDate = #3/12/2003 3:00:00 PM#
    Set myRecurrPatt = myApptItem.GetRecurrencePattern
    Set myOddApptItem = myRecurrPatt.GetOccurrence(myDate)

    'Save the existing subject. Change the subject and
    'starting time for this particular appointment
    'and save it.
    saveSubject = myOddApptItem.Subject
    myOddApptItem.Subject = "Meet NEW Boss"
    newDate = #3/12/2003 3:30:00 PM#
    myOddApptItem.Start = newDate
    myOddApptItem.Save

    'Get the recurrence pattern for the master
    'AppointmentItem. Access the collection of
    'exceptions to the regular appointments.
    Set myRecurrPatt = myApptItem.GetRecurrencePattern
    Set myException = myRecurrPatt.Exceptions.Item(1)

    'Display the original date, time, and subject
    'for this exception.
    MsgBox myException.OriginalDate & ": " & saveSubject

    'Display the current date, time, and subject
    'for this exception.
    MsgBox myException.AppointmentItem.Start & ": " & _
    myException.AppointmentItem.Subject
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, there are zero elements in the array. The [online tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869544.aspx) probably had an exception on that example recurring patterned appointment. You on the other hand do not on your Outlook calendar.

Consider wrapping the Exceptions.Item() in a loop. This way if the array is empty nothing will be processed:

```
Dim ItemIndex As Variant
...


For Each ItemIndex in myRecurrPatt.Exceptions.Items
  Set myException = myRecurrPatt.Exceptions.Item(ItemIndex)

  'Display the original date, time, and subject
  'for this exception.
  MsgBox myException.OriginalDate & ": " & saveSubject

  'Display the current date, time, and subject
  'for this exception.
  MsgBox myException.AppointmentItem.Start & ": " & _
  myException.AppointmentItem.Subject

Next ItemIndex
```

Answer (score 0):

The Exceptions class provides the [Count](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/ff868300.aspx) property which you may check out before trying to access any item in the collection.

I'd suggest breaking the chain of property and method calls and declaring each property or method on a single line of code. Thus, you will be able to find what property or method call causes the issue.

Finally, you may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) article in MSDN helpful.